# Error: Account not associated with this Mint

Tags: anchor

https://explorer.solana.com/address/3NPd4HALRXz2r2MHEujyitb7vfQvuqVS29mY9Qvw3n2M

Trying to transfer an NFT, but it just does not work

> Program logged: "Instruction: TransferChecked"
> Program logged: "Error: Account not associated with this Mint"
> Program consumed: 4532 of 200000 compute units
> Program returned error: "custom program error: 0x3"

Comment: Kindly provide more details and add comprehensive code samples to the question. Attempting to answer your question without any of that would have to involve a lot of guesswork and assumptions

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because, judging by the last transfer transaction on that NFT, it looks like the OP eventually figured it out.

Answer (score 2):

The token account balance seems to be zero. There is no NFT to be transferred in this account.

[image]

Comment: Judging by the date on the last transfer transaction I think the OP figured it out.